# Extract a single property from an object that has always been anonymous?

Tags: c#

Every answer I've found relies on the anonymous object having originally been a typed object.  I have an object that was initialized with `return new {x, y, width, height, guid}`, and I'd like to get the `guid` (which I'll then use to get the original/complete object).

```
private void ListboxContainer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object selected = e.AddedItems[0];
    selectedObjectText.Text = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(selected.ToString());
    // -> "{ type = tableBlock, x = 100, y = 100, width = 300, height = 50, z = 50, guid = 0f179336-3b38-4e36-94b7-671ffd8017d9 }"

    Console.WriteLine(selected.GetType().ToString());
    // -> "<>f__AnonymousType2`7[System.String,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Int32,System.String]"

    dynamic d = selected;

    Console.WriteLine("guid: " + d.guid);
    // -> RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'guid'

    // What I eventually need to do:
    //IDrawable selected = activeMap.GetDrawable(e.AddedItems[0].guid);
}
```

I'm looking for a safer/more-performant way to get the GUID (which I *know* is there) than manually parsing the string for it.  For more information regarding what's happening before this, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896754/supplying-typed-objects-to-zoomablecanvas) post (which, unfortunately, got passed up by SO, so this entire post is just about a work-around).

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 3):

If you are returning your anonymous object to a dynamic, you can then invoke the property at runtime, though this will throw a runtime error if the property does not exist.

```
public dynamic Test()
{
    return new {var1 = "", var2 = Guid.NewGuid()};
}

var output = Test();
Console.WriteLine(output.var2);
```

The question is, WHY are you doing this?  Is there any reason you can't just return new objects from the get go?  While you can access the properties of a dynamic, this is somewhat dangerous, not quite as performant, and obviously not type safe.

Comment: I'm working on a program that draws to a `ZoomableCanvas`, fed via an `ItemsSource` that requires a generic object.  For some reason, it fails to work when I upcast a complete object from (e.g.) TableBlock to an object, but if I manually create a generic object via `return new { param1, param2 };` it works fine.  The code in this SO post is in the SelectionChanged listener.  I'll update the post with the complete method.  Other SO post regarding the typing issue (that seemed to have been passed up by SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896754/supplying-typed-objects-to-zoomablecanvas

Comment: // What I eventually need to do:
    //IDrawable selected = activeMap.GetDrawable(e.AddedItems[0].guid);.  This comment is troubling to me.  you're accessing the added items of e at that point.  That is not a dynamic.  If you inspect the e.AddedItems[0] at runtime, what type is it?  I suspect it is an object, not a dynamic, which would cause you problems. The commented in code that you currently have in your question does not throw the error.

Comment: I was just following a variety of other SO posts that said dynamic typing was the way to go in .Net 4.0.  When I print `e.AddedItems[0].GetType()`, I get "<>f__AnonymousType2`7[System.String,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Int32,System.String]".  When I set a breakpoint, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/cHwiOmF.png.  It looks to have no type.

Comment: Interesting, that definitely appears to be your anonymous type.  I can't reproduce your error so I'm not certain what's causing you to still receive the error

Comment: Oh well.  It's working now via Regex parsing, then using the GUID to look up the original object in from a table.  Yay, workarounds.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to get this done :).  While a workaround, probably not a very efficient one :P.

Comment: Yeah... Oh, well.  The stupid thing is that I had to implement a workaround for part of a workaround.  None of this would be an issue if I could figure out that other problem in the linked post, haha.

Answer (score 0):

This very identical code running fine here (no such "`'object' does not contain a definition for 'guid'`" error) :

```
object o =
    new
        {
            type = "tableBlock",
            x = 100,
            y = 100,
            width = 300,
            height = 50,
            z = 50,
            guid = Guid.Parse("6d405dcf-9f40-4b2c-8a26-588259aee557")
        };
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
dynamic d = o;
Console.WriteLine("guid: " + d.guid);
```

Comment: I removed my original comment because I was actually in error when I first read your post.  You are still accessing d as a dynamic, not an anonymous type, which would not make a difference if you were inside or outside of the method context.  If it was an anonymous type, it would make a difference in terms of accessing the type, not the values.  Apologies for causing confusion :).

Comment: I just updated the post with a little more information regarding context of the object.  Maybe you'll spot something new?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. That doesn't change the fact that I don't get the error you are questioning. As you can see above, I created an anonymous object, pass it as type object to variable of type dynamic. Then I can access `guid` property without getting error?? I can't replicate the problem so far.